# Total probability

Tags: probability, distributions

suppose we have two non negative discrete random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, let $D=X_1+X_2$ and $UPL$ is a non negative number, I want to find probability of $(D\leq UPL-1)$.
in one article, they wrote
$P(D \leq UPL− 1)=P(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2| min(x_1+x_2-1)=UPL)$.
but I dont know how they wrote that, and if there is a another answer, help me

Comment: The right hand side makes little sense, because the minimum of one value $x_1+x_2-1$ is the value itself, making applying $\min$ superfluous.  Are you sure you have reproduced the article's formula *exactly?*

Comment: yes, the article title is "Copula-Based Bivariate ZIP Control Chart for Monitoring
Rare Events"